# Does openvpn Access Server use RPC bind or other port mapping services ?

Tags: openvpn, rhel6, portmap

We are running an access server which has a port mapping service running on 111. Does OpenVPN require port mapping services. We currently use two way connectivity (i.e) Machines on the server side subnet should be able to connect to the VPN users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, openvpn does not use rpcbind.